# DTW and kNN-DTW time complexity

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, dtw

I have implemented KNN using a custom DTW metric with sci-kit learn and as shown below:

```
def dtw(t1, t2):
    distance = fastdtw(t1, t2)[0]
    return distance
model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1, metric=dtw)
```

Additionally, I also implemented standalone DTW for template matching as shown below:

```
 def calc_dtw():
    predictions = []
    for i in range(len(X)): #X is an array containing X values to be predicted
        distances = []
        for j in range(len(self.X_)):
            distances.append(fastdtw(X[i], self.X_[j])[0]) #self.X_ are the templates
        closest = distances.index(min(distances))
        predictions.append(self.y_[closest])
    
     return predictions
```

Both implementations of DTW use the same 'fast dtw' library. I ran a test to calculate how long it takes for each algorithm to compute a prediction and results showed that kNN-DTW is faster than standalone DTW. Shouldn't standalone DTW (quadratic time complexity) be faster than kNN-DTW (cubic time complexity)? Is this because of an error in my DTW implementation?

Comment: How large was your dataset on which you benchmarked both the algorithms ?

Comment: Hi @mujjiga, the dataset used was identical. This was repeated several times with data between 1 training sample to 15 training samples. In all cases DTW was slower.

Comment: If you are saying you benchmarked on 15 samples but repeated it many time, then it is wrong way to conduct the experiments. The sample are too less  for empirically calculating using the speed using cpu clock time. You will need to use large values of `n` to see the difference between `O(n^2)` and `O(n^3)` on the cpu clock time.

Comment: @mujjiga Noted. However, if I had to use more training samples, the result should be that KNN-DTW is much slower than DTW? or is the difference between them almost negligible?